# Diagonal matrix properly in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

My code works but I'm just curious to see if someone knows how to do this but properly using Armadillo library. 
Thanks for your time :)

```
arma::mat W = arma::mat(4, 4, arma::fill::ones);
arma::mat D = arma::mat(4, 4, arma::fill::zeros);

for (size_t i = 0; i < W.n_rows; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < W.n_cols; j++)
    {
        D(i, i) += W(i, j);
    }
}
std::cout<< "W = \n"<< W <<std::endl;
std::cout<< "D = \n"<< D <<std::endl;
```

Comment: You should describe what your code is suppose to do. Right now anyone that could answer your question needs to first understand what is the question by looking into the code you have provided.

Comment: yeah indeed I forgot to say what was the purpose of the code. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are summing the elements in each row in the `W` matrix and putting the result in the diagonal of the `D` matrix. That is, you are summing elements over the "columns" dimension. This is very easy to do in armadillo and does not require any manual loop.

Armadillo has a [`sum`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sum) function with a few overloads. One of these overloads receives a second parameter that you can use to specify in which dimension you want to perform the sum. Just specify the second dimension (index `1`) and you get the proper result.

However, the result you get from `arma::sum(W, 1)` will be a vector. It makes sense, since you are summing over one of the dimensions of the matrix. Just pass the result to `arma::diagmat` and you get the same `D` matrix as with you original code. Your code can then be replaced by

```cpp
arma::mat W = arma::mat(4, 4, arma::fill::ones);
arma::mat D = arma::mat(4, 4, arma::fill::zeros);

W.print("W");
arma::diagmat(arma::sum(W, 1)).print("D");
```

---

**Note**: I have used the `.print` method to print the matrices, in case you don't know about it. It is easier to use than using std::cout;

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was not so hard I found the diagmat function but didn't know how to use it.